# Neo4J Node's ego network with python

Tags: python, graph, neo4j

I'm working with Neo4J for the first time and I need to output the ego network of a node whose name was given in input. I'm using python and `neo4j` library to run queries into my graph.

[image]

I'm sorry for the colors, but it's the only way to explain the scenario.
The blue node is the input node and the graph you see is the output of Neo4J of the blue node's ego network and it is exactly what I want to achieve in my query. The green edges are the nodes directly connected to the blue, yellow edges are self-relationships and red edges are relationships between the node's neighbours.

With this query I only achieve the green relationships:

```
MATCH p=(node {name:$name})-[*1]-(othernodes) 
with *, relationships(p) as r  
RETURN node,r,othernodes
```

I modified this query and I achieved also the yellow relationships (thanks to the comment below)

```
MATCH p=(node {name:$name})-[*1]-(othernodes) 
with *, relationships(p) as r  
MATCH s=(othernodes)-[*0..1]-(othernodes)
with *, relationships(s) as e
RETURN node,r,e,othernodes
```

But I'm still missing the correct query to achieve also the red edges. Can you help me out with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean "but I lost 2 nodes" are the gray nodes without the yellow edges?

Comment: Exactly @jose_bacoy

Comment: thanks. nice question because of a good example and it includes a diagram.

Comment: please edit your question and put the result that you want.

Answer (score 1):

When you write this query below,

```
MATCH s=(othernodes)-[*1]-(othernodes)
```

it means you want othernodes which has an edge onto itself. So it will not include those nodes in gray. If you want to include the nodes (in gray) on the result, then change it to:

```
MATCH s=(othernodes)-[*0..1]-(othernodes)
```

which means give me othernodes that has zero or a relationship (edge) onto itself.

Edited: due to comments below

Comment: With [*..1] the result is the same, but with [*0..1] it works and I can also see the two lost nodes! But what about red edges?

Comment: You will not get red edges because you use the same node "othernodes" in this line:  MATCH s=(othernodes)-[*0..1]-(othernodes).  What is the actual result that you want? You cannot ask for two answers in one question. Do you understand it from my point of view?

Comment: I'm not asking two questions, I'm asking the correct query to achieve that picture. So green, yellow and red edges. I'm still missing the red ones

Comment: Let us count:  #1) I lost 2 nodes in gray  #2) what about the red edges.

Comment: Well, my queries were my attempts to achieve that picture, but I made wrong queries, so I asked the correct one to achieve that picture. I think that's a pretty clear question...

Comment: No it's not clear